# How can I fix my X11 draw garbled icons?

Tags: xorg, x11, drivers

I'm running linux mint 12:

```
$ cat /etc/issue     
Linux Mint 12 Lisa \n \l
```

This started happening recently:

[image: sample garbled images]

And I'm not sure why. It's not just limited to the above icons and text.

```
$ lspci | grep VGA 
04:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation NV44A [GeForce 6200] (rev a1)
```

I haven't noticed anything amiss in kern, syslog, or dmesg, but I really don't know what's causing this issue or where to look. How can I make my X draw properly?